# IBM WebSphere Application Server Fix Pack Installation

Tags: installation, ibm

I'm trying to install a fix pack for IBM WebSphere Application 6.0.2.15 in Windows 2003. This was installed without the IBM Installation Manager (don't know how). 
  Now I have to install the Fix pack for it. Any pointers on how to proceed with the installation of the fix pack? 
  Also does IBM Rational Application Developer contain WebSphere Application Server in its installation files ?

Comment: FIX is a trading platform NOT a general tag for "I want something fixing"

Comment: read the tag description (Financial Information eXchange (FIX) Protocol) - I was just pointing out the difference as a lot of people make this mistake. I meant to be helpful rather than snarkey sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link from the IBM support site with instructions for fix packing to V6.0.2.15, [Readme for IBM WebSphere Application Server V6.0.2.15](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27008530#steps).

If you're looking to fix pack up from V6.0.2.15 to, say, V6.0.2.43:

- select "Fix Pack 43 (6.0.2.43)" from [Fix list for WebSphere Application Server Version 6.0.2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006876) (you can also use this link to find installation instructions for other fix packs),
- click on "Download Fixpack 43" (or whichever version you are fix packing to),
- then pick Windows from the tabbed menu and scroll down to "Installation Instructions".

Comment: Thanks Chris, I dowloaded the PAK file. How do I install the fix Pack, since WAS is not listed in the IBM Installation Manager ?

Comment: Finally I managed to install the fix Pack. I installed the Update Installer for WebSphere Application Server and used it to install the Fix pack V6.0.2.43. Thanks Chris for you guidance.